# What navigation application can I use on Ubuntu phone devices, is it good as Google Map navigation?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, devices, navigation, google-maps

What navigation application can I use on Ubuntu phone devices (the BQ Aquaris E4.5 & E5), while driving?

Is it as good as the android default navigation system?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I created [GPS Navigation](https://uappexplorer.com/app/navigator.costales) (search it into the Ubuntu Phone Store).
You can see how it is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-nOsd2NAGmI
Feel free to give me your feedback :)
A hug!

Comment: great thank you! i cannot test at the moment, i do not have a phone.